# Character array and address of character array

Tags: c

So if I have the code:

```
void main (void)
{
     char s[] = "Programming is hard";

    printf("%s", &s);
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;

}
```

They both produce the same result. But &s should be the address of the character array right? so shouldnt' printf prints out the adress instead of what is stored in the address?

Thanks.

Comment: By definition (the value of an) address of an array is the same (value as) the address of the array's 1st element.

Comment: To print an addres, prinft("%p", &s);

Comment: ... `printf("%p", (void*) &s);` @GabrielPellegrino

Comment: the '%s' prints what is at where the address points.  to print out the actual address use : '%p'

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of the first `printf` is undefined due to a mismatched formatter.

In many respects, your compiler is being kind to you.

Don't do that!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print out an address of a variable, use %x or %p as formatter.

Comment: `x` is not correct unless the pointer value is casted to best `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Also when using `p` the pointer value needs to be casted to `void*`.